# Java unable to convert collection of collection with implementation type to interface type

Tags: java, collections

```
ImplementedType implements InterfaceType
```

I'm able to convert

```
Map<String, ImplementedType> m1 = Maps.newHashMap();
Map<String, ? extends InterfaceType> m2 = m1;
```

But i'm unable to convert

```
Map<String, List<ImplementedType>> m1 = Maps.newHashMap();
Map<String, List<? extends InterfaceType>> m2 = m1;



Error: java: incompatible types:
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<ImplementedType>> 
cannot be converted to 
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<? extends InterfaceType>>
```

However i'm able to do a type unsafe conversion to a 'Map' first and it works. But is this really a good idea?

```
Map<String, List<? extends IOGInvoicePageCountInfo>> m2 = (Map) m1;
```

Comment: Casting via (Map) uses **raw types**, something that you really really not want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good idea. That cast is unsafe. For example:

```
final Map<String, List<Integer>> m1 = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, List<? extends Number>> m2 = (Map) m1;

m2.put("", Arrays.asList(new Float(0.0)));
System.out.println(m1.get("").get(0).intValue());
```

will cause:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

The correct type of `m2` is:

```
final Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Number>> m2 = m1;
```

This is type safe as you no longer can put incompatible elements into `m1` via `m2` - previous example will cause compilation error.